# Is there a git plugin for the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, git

Is there some nice git-intregation that makes life easier for the Delphi IDE (2010)?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit) from inside Delphi IDE 2007 and above with the File Browser Feature, TortoiseGit integrate into Windows Explorer, so you will access it's command from File Browse Inside the IDE.

if you have older version than 2007, you can use [IBrowser](http://www.blog.issamsoft.com/index.php?q=en/node/39) which provide more featuers than File Browser beside support older Delphi versions.

I do the same but with TortoiseSVN

Comment: Version Insight is actualyl a 3rd-party plugin by some guy Uli something.
I managed to add Git into XE2 using it. see svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/radstudioverins/code/trunk