# Does C++ Builder 2009 Work with Git?

Tags: git, c++builder

Can you manage source control with C++ Builder 2009's IDE with Git? I know I can do it outside of the IDE, I'm curious if it will work in an integrated way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature in the IDE, but you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482015/is-there-a-git-plugin-for-the-delphi-ide). I think it's a good workaround.