# Call git commit & push commands from within Delphi XE2

Tags: git, delphi, version-control, delphi-xe2

I'm learning Git and I like it so far.

**I'd like to be able to add, commit & push from within Delphi XE2 IDE**

I figured I could just create a custom entry under `Tools`, so I added this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" commit -a -c "Commit message here..." $NAME()

It didn't work. I took the command line & executed it directly, I got this:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I googled a lot, but I couldn't find any useful tip that would help me solve this.

Any idea how to **add, commit & push from within Delphi XE2 IDE**?

PS. Custom plugins would be OK, I use `GExperts` & `CnPack`, but AFAIK they don't help here

[image: Tool Properties Settings]

Comment: Some help from here perhaps, [`Is there a git plugin for the Delphi IDE?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482015/576719).

Comment: What happens when you use **working** command from within Tools menu? Also, please post whole tool setup.

Comment: The message means that you are running git in a directory that is not part of a git repository. So the tool entry is being run in the wrong place.

Comment: @LURD: Thanks, I actually read this post, but I don't have the File Browser panel when I work, it's waste of space for me to keep it on. I'd rather use the `Tools` menu, much less evasive!

Comment: @KeithMiller: I'm not sure I can change the directory **and** run git to commit using one command...unless I call a batch script that does this, hum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are 2 options.

1) You may provide project's directory in "Working directory". That probably would be the best option if you mainly work only on one project.

2) Use command prompt to change to that directory. Use `cmd` for Program and `/C cd $PATH($EDNAME) && "C:\Path to git\git.exe" commit -a` for Parameters. Git will add all changed files to the index, prompt you for the message and then commit. If you would like command prompt to stay open after that, change switch `/C` to `/K`.

Comment: Thank you very much man, your answer didn't exactly meet my needs, but it definitely set me on the right path. For those interested, I called [this dos batch script](http://pastebin.com/GF8R3n8G) from Delphi. Parameters are, as Teloah suggested, is `$PATH($EDNAME)`

Answer (score 1):

A much better and more integrated approach would be to use an existing plugin. For example Version Insight Plus.

Comment: Uwe's site bitcommander.de has been closed for a year now. Is there a public repository for Version Insight Plus?

Comment: If only I can find/download it :(

Comment: @LURD I think you'll need to get it from the repo: http://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudioverins/